# PHP code scraping a URL suddenly stopped working

Tags: php

```
$url = 'the web address I want to get the first and second numbers close to $' ;
$str = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match_all('/ ([$]) *(\d+(:?.\d+)?)/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$i=0;
foreach ($matches as $val) {
    if($i==0) $first=$val[2] ;
    if($i==3) $second=$val[2] ;
    $i++;    
}
$bad_symbols = array(",", "."); $first = str_replace($bad_symbols, "", $first); 
$bad_symbols = array(",", "."); $second = str_replace($bad_symbols, "", $second); 

echo $first . "</br>";
echo $second;
```

it worked fine till yesterday
what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you look at the result of file_get_contents($url) ? Maybe the web site you're scraping changd something.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: So what's the problem? What it does now?

Comment: Please give us more information about what exactly doesn’t work anymore and use a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 3):

I see at least two possible explanations :

- The HTML of the site has changed ; maybe only a little bit -- but enough to get you in trouble.

  - You could test for the return value of `preg_match_all`
  - if it's false, it means your regex didn't match -- which may indicate the content of the HTML pageis not the same...
  - Then, you might have to modify your regex
- The admin of the server (or it can be done in the code generating the page) has banned you

  - Maybe the website has detected it was **scraped** by you (either because you were going too hard on their server, or they saw their content on your site)
  - And they banned your IP (for instance)
  - To detect that, try to get the return value of `file_get_contents` ; if it's false, it might be the cause of the problem
  - Can you try getting that HTML page from your server, using wget in command-line ?
- A third one, as suggestd by others : maybe the configuration of your server has changed, and you can't use file_get_content over HTTP anymore...

  - A solution would be to use curl, for instance
  - Check in your configuration the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) directive

If you activate [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) ([see also](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)), you might also get some informations that could prove usefull...

Comment: It’s __scraped__ not scrapped

Answer (score 0):

Maybe system administrator has changed allow_url_fopen directive, that means you can't access files that are not on your server. Check what file_get_contents() returns, because you gave us very little information about error.

Another problem, as mentioned above, could be that remote site has been changed :)